# Adding the second values from a vector<pair> which appear before this value

Tags: c++, loops, stdvector, std-pair

So, I'm attempting to make a function that shifts through a vector of pairs and adds the second value of to the previous values to the current target. However, I'm unsure of how to loop backwards to grab all of the values that were previously before the target.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
int cWeight (KEY_T key) const
{
    int size = _valueToWeightMap.size();

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        if (_valueToWeightMap[x].first == key && x == 0)
            return _valueToWeightMap[x].second;

        if (_valueToWeightMap[x].first == key && x != 0)
            return _valueToWeightMap[x].second + _valueToWeightMap[x - 1].second;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `_valueToWeightMap` is the name of the vector, and `KEY_T` is just a `typename` that looks for strings.

Currently, the function only grabs the secondary value from the pair right behind it in the vector, however I want it to grab the secondary value from all the ones behind it. How would I go about doing this?

Here's some things I added to the vector.

```
dist1.add("Helmet", 1);
dist1.add("Boots", 10);
dist1.add("Gloves", 20);
dist1.add("Cloud", 15);
dist1.add("Ring", 4);
dist1.add("Wind", 12);
```

So, what I want the function to do is this:

1. The pair in position 0 has its second value equal to 1, so the function should return one.
2. The pair in the position 1 has its second value equal to 10, so the function should return 11. (10 + 1)
3. The pair in position 2 has its second value equal to 20, so it should return 31. (20 + 10 + 1)
   and so on.

Comment: *adds the second value of to the previous values to the current target* I didn't quite follow what you mean by that. Adding some textual description with sample data and what  you hope to see the function do to the data will be very useful.

Comment: I agree, this is a little unclear. Your question would benefit from you showing a small sample of data and explaining how you would want them to be manipulated.

Comment: @RSahu Fixed it!

Comment: @Tas Hope this adds some more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
int cWeight (KEY_T key) const
{
    int size = _valueToWeightMap.size();

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        // Find the appropriate key
        if (_valueToWeightMap[x].first == key)
        {
            // Start with the value of this one
            auto values = _valueToWeightMap[x].second;
            // Add all values lower in the map:
            for (auto i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            {
                values += _valueToWeightMap[i].second;
            }
            return values;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here you don't require any special handling for the first case.